# Which is better WebSocket or Long Polling in Signalr?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, long-polling

I want to make `Asp.NET` Web Chat Application and found that `Signalr` is best option for this. I found one sample Project with `Long Polling` but it seems that it takes such a long time to send message or it just cancels it. I want to make speedy Chat app like `Facebook` and `Google`.
Please give me better way to go ahead.

Comment: Why downvoted ? let me knw if i need to correct anything ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best thing about `SignalR` is that you don't have to worry about `Long Polling` and `WebSockets`, but the framework itself deals with it.

When first launched, SignalR will try to use `WebSockets`, because it is the newest and uses the least broadband. Then, it will fallback to `Server Sent Events`, `Forever Frame` and `Long Polling`, all depending on the technology available on the server and on the client.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr
Here you have these concepts explained.

To sum things up, you shouldn't specify the framework which technology to use, but it should determine for itself (when dealing with each client - browser), depending on the available technology on the server and on the client.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: I am using `asp.net` not mvc. according to you, which one should be better ? I have many to many web app using `server send events` and 'long polling'. But I am looking for one to one chat and i have one sample project with 'long polling', which is not working.

Comment: I will say it again, if you set a project to use SignalR, by default it will try to use WebSockets. If because of various reasons WebSockets are not available (because of the server or because of the client), it will try Server Sent Events, and so on. 
Of course, using WebSockets is recommended rather than using Long Polling, which is only used by SignalR as a last resort.

Is my answer more clear now?

Comment: Can you provide me one working private chat sample ?

Comment: I actually used this tutorial when started  learning SignalR.

Comment: Is it working fine ? Actually, i dnt have enough time to learn everything right nw so i need any working sample..

Comment: Yes, it does what it is supposed to do: public chat in public rooms, private chat with 2 users. But remember, it is only made as a tutorial and it is not in any way production ready.

Comment: Ohk, thank you. Let me check it out. I want it for unlimited private chat users that i will make it dynamically myself.